# How to press "Ctrl+Shift+Q" in AutoIt

Tags: controls, autoit, shift

I have an application which has a shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit it. I want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> via AutoIt to exit my application. I tried it as below:

```
Send("{LCTRL} {LSHIFT} Q")
```

and

```
ControlSend("{LCTRL} {LSHIFT} Q")
```

But none of them did work. Please guide me to do it the right way.

Answer (score 4):

You want something like:

```
Send("{CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}q{CTRLUP}{SHIFTUP}")
```

What you are sending presses the keys individually in sequence, rather than chaining them together. Hope that helps!

<sup>Source: [www.autoitscript.com](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below option

```
Send("^+{F}")
```

The keylists are available in the AutoIt Help link, take a look at [Send Auto Keys List](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm)